# PowerBI: How to remove filter on specific column in chart

Tags: filter, charts, powerbi, multiple-columns, slicers

I'm working with specific columns from a table. I have a "data" column for each month of the year and a "data_last_month" column for December + percentages. I have a chart filtered by slicer (year slicer, quarter slicer - last month of the quarter). I want to filter only the "data" column and "percentages". I dont want to filter the "data_last_month" column. However, I need to keep this column in one chart to see the differences between the month at the end of the quarter and the month at the end of the year.
[image: My visualisation]

You can see how it looks, but when I click on the quarter slicer (1,2,3), the data_last_month column is removed because it only shows data for December. So how can I simply turn off the slicer for this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to confuse you earlier.
I played a little bit, and I found a solution that worked.

1. I created a true/false column in Calendar table, that is true when month is December:

   **IsDecember Flag = IF('Dim Date'[Date].[Month] = "December", TRUE())**

(My dataset has limited date table, you can use other columns like Monthnumber, Monthname,etc.)

2. Created a measure as follows:

   **Amount December =
   CALCULATE( SUM('Fact Table'[data_last_month]), ALL('Dim Date'[Date].[Month]), ALL('Dim Date'[Date].[Quarter])
   , 'Dim Date'[IsDecember Flag] = TRUE())**
3. Added this measure to the visual. I apply a screenshot. You can see I have selected Jan, Feb, Mar in the slicer, however December value remains a constant.

[image: Click here to see screenshot.]

I hope this helps! I am sure this is a workaround tho. Probably there are much more efficient ways for this to be resolved with only a measure. Until then, you can present this as a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. I changed the IsDecember Flag a bit, but that's because I have a different access to the date table.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a measure, that will remove date filters from data_last_month, it could work. Something like:

Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[data_last_month], ALL('Calendar'))

That way calendar table will not filter the data for december and it will always stay the same. This is provided your slicers come from a date table (calendar).

Place this measure in the visual. Hope this works!

Comment: When I make your suggestion, I will get the counts for all the years. So data_last_month shows the counted value of each year and does not show only the counted value of December in one year. I tried a modification: ...ALL('Date table'[Quarter]), but this is again filtered by slicer. Maybe I am missing something.